Max. energy of X-rays produced in an X-ray tube if 99% of the electrons' KE is thermally dissipated
(I think this question may be what the 'no homework merchant' meant to ask here.)
I was working through a question that asked me to find the maximum energy produced from an X-ray tube with accelerating voltage, $V$. I was also given that 99% of the electrons' KE is thermally dissipated*, and that a single electron can produce exactly one X-ray.
My initial thoughts were that the kinetic energy of a single electron would be $E_k = eV$ (assuming they start from rest) and 99% of this energy would be dissipated as heat, leaving only 1% to be converted to an X-ray. So the energy of an X-ray produced would be $E = 0.01E_k = 0.01eV$.
However the answer was simply $E=eV$ which leads me to believe I may have interpreted this (*) statement wrong: I thought it meant that 99% of each electron's KE was dissipated as heat, but now I think it may mean that, overall, 99% of all the electrons' overall KE is dissipated as heat. In the maximum-energy X-ray case, 100% of the electrons KE can be converted to an X-ray. Am I correct in saying this?

It is true that X-ray tubes are quite inefficient.

I've tried to clarify my question to emphasize this is what I'm asking: "(now I think it may mean that) overall, 99% of all the electrons' overall KE is dissipated as heat. In the maximum-energy X-ray case, 100% of the electrons KE can be converted to an X-ray. Am I correct in saying this?"

It's a stochastic process. Most electrons that strike the anode deposit all of their energy as heat. A minority produce a photon with random energy between 0 and $E_k$: their remaining energy is deposited as heat. Multiple photons are possible, but unlikely.
